# Hide the field along with the row in SharePoint form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, css, html

I was able to hide the textbox and label form SharePoint from using the below code. But there is a row which still there after removing text which looks like a gap between textboxes how do i remove it using css

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use the below script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type=text/javascript>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('nobr:contains("field name")').closest('tr').hide();
   });
</script>
```